# Do I need to specify a client for connect-redis?

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I'm trying to use redis on a node express server to store user sessions, by using the connect-redis([on Github](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis)) library. And I find this block of settings works well:

```
var app = express();

app.use(session({
  secret: 'hahahahahahahahahaha',
  cookie: { maxAge: 36000000 },
  store: new redisStore(),
}))
```

Notice I didn't pass any params to `new redisStore()` and it also works for now (in its documentation a `client` is passed), guess it's using localhost and default port by default.

But I'm worrying, if I put my server on AWS EC2 in the future which is a shared server, will that be a problem if I don't specify a client? Say, will redis conflicts with other servers also hosting on that EC2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *are* using a redis client here. You just relinquished the configuration of the client though. That will be a problem in the future, as (presumably) you will be deploying on AWS in a cluster. The redis client needs to be common across instances.

If you don't define the port number and other details of the client, you basically are undoing the purpose of having state management. Your redis clients will be limited to your own instance.

Go through http://redis.io/topics/partitioning for more info.

The idea is to have one (or a cluster) of redis instances that run independent of your AWS instances, so that state is shared across all of your instances. *That* is why you need to have complete control of your redis client

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer - just what I need

Comment: In that case do I need to use redis.createClient(), or simply specify host & port?

Comment: You can simply specify the host and port for now, but when you deploy to a distributed cluster on production and you need to scale up, you'll need to implement some sort of distributed cache. THe link I've provided in the answer has more details